# How would comercially available Fetch Modi/Sylladexes affect the economy AND the storage of items

Tags: society, technology, economy

Let me pitch you a setting:

The year is 2018 and a start up company that goes by the name of "PlebTech" has released several FUNCTIONING Fetch Modi/Sylladexes to the market.

**What it is:** A Sylladex is an inventory system used within Homestuck, A Sylladex is essentially a deck of specially designed cards that can store objects within a pocket dimension that can be retrieved by pressing on a button on the card. Whilst a Fetch Modi is how one retrieves cards from the Sylladex

(Think of the Sylladex as a Deck Case and the Fetch Modi as means of individually retrieving cards from the the Deck Case)

**Limitations:** Despite trying to emulate the Sylladex/ Fetch Modi system as much as possible PlebTech ran into a few problems while building the device(s), The most prominent of these being that each deck can only store 35 cards and if someone "Captchalogue's" something while their deck is full then one random item shall be ejected (which can lead to severe injuries depending on the size and speed of the object after it's ejection).

**Types of Fetch Modi (Currently) Available on the Market:** Wallet Modus, Tree Modus, Stack Modus, Array Modus, and Hash Map Modus

Cost: 10 card booster pack= \$7.46, One Fetch Modi= \$65.32, Complete Deck of 35 cards= \$261 (Note: One does not need a Fetch Modi in order to use Captchacards, it just makes the retrieval of cards quicker and more convienent for the user

**Limitations Part 2**: if the object you are attempting to eject is bigger than the room/area you a currently in then the object will fail to eject and you hear an rather irritating BEEP sound.

Now unto to my question: How does this affect the economy AND the storages of goods as we know it?

Note: Please refer to this link: http://mspaintadventures.wikia.com/wiki/Sylladex

Note: If perishable food is stored within a Captchacard it shall not rot

Note: houses, skyscrapers, humans, and anything connected to the ground cannot be captchalouged (apples, birds, and antimatter can be captchalogued alongside everything else)

How does this affect the economy AND the storages of goods as we know it?

Comment: I'm severely confused. Pocket dimensions? Decks? Cards? You're using too much story specific terminology, as well as asking an insanely broad question. Is this technology economically viable? Pocket dimensions? Carrying a tank in your back pocket? Uhm ... I think ***YES*** would be an understatement. So what's the real question here?

Comment: I just edited the question including this information

Comment: feel free to take a crack at it with all this extra information

Comment: Assuming this technology did not exist before, it completely wipes a whole level of the economy out. It's a technological revolution the likes of which no one would have imagined for another 1000 years - right up there with FTL travel, and time machines. Would it be economically viable? My answer is still the same: Yes. Very much so. How would this affect the world? Profoundly. However, your question is far too broad for WB SE's scope. Profoundly out of scope.

Comment: should I move this question to another question answering site? and if so which one should I use? (I'm thinking Quora but I need to be sure)

Comment: You ask how this affects the economy and storage of goods.  What if I ask you the same question?  Where do you think the economy goes?  You mention food doesn't rot, which suggests you have some very powerful time-manipulation effects available at your disposal.

Comment: sorry to say this but I have no idea how the economy functions

Comment: ask a question about anatomy or the effects of a fictional parasite on the human body and I can answer that, But I CANNOT answer a question about the economy (without making gross oversimplifications)

Comment: If you 'captchalouge' a 'Sylladex,' does the universe implode due to putting extradimensional spaces inside each other?

Comment: Actually I forgot to mention this but Sylladexes/Fetch Modi cannot be captchalogued

Comment: If you want to have a dollar sign $ in you text, then you have to put a \ before it, like this: \$12.50 Then it will appear in your text correctly.

Comment: Please remove all Homestuck-specific references and just talk about pocket dimensions.  It's a more universally known term.

Answer (score 3):

Consider how much money and effort goes into transporting *stuff* around.

Food. Refined goods. Raw materials.

Thousands of huge container ships full of *stuff* crossing the oceans. Hundreds of thousands of trains travelling the world, full of the same. Millions of trucks.

Assuming that the price of this technology is not insanely overblown, and it passed safety and quality testing (food doesn't spoil, or get poisoned, products are not affected somehow), all those industries would disappear overnight.

And whenever there's a large economic upset, there's also a political upset, a societal upset, and (in this case) most likely war. And that's if you're not immediately arrested by the government and your technology declared a national secret, only usable by the alphabet agencies.

My prediction would be that the world would be immersed in terrible turmoil the second this tech became available.

Hundreds of thousands of people out of work? Check.

The rich feeling threatened by the loss of thousands of profitable industries, including a major drop in the demand for oil? Check.

Massive political and military instability as Saudi Arabia and many other countries essentially become bankrupt overnight? Check.

What more do you really need?

Smuggling goods would become laughably easy to do. Terrorists could be walking around with bombs in their back pockets, not to mention entire arsenals of conventional weaponry. War would change in inventive and unexpected ways.

The list just goes on, and on, and on.

Comment: Thank you for answering this AndreiROM! especially considering the fact that this question  is outside the scope of WB SE

Comment: @anaspiringauthor - I wanted to say more than a comment would allow. I also retracted my close vote, as it would be hypocritical at this point. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why humans cannot be capchalogued if birds can.  I am not connected to the ground more than an apple.  If humans can be stored and if stored food does not rot then a stored human will not age or need food / water.  Time will not pass for the stored.  The scifi possibilities for this aspect alone are mind boggling.  Population control by storing large numbers of people.  Rapid evacuation by railgun of the stored.  A medic is now a guy with a sylladex, who drops the sick and injured off at the hospital later, to be retrieved and treated if they have the funds.  That is the easy stuff.